# Is this a Salesforce bug? If so, how do I report it?

Tags: apex, map, sobjecttype

Running this code snippet Anonymously produces the following error:

> "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object"

```
Map<SObjectType,List<Id>> myMap = new Map<SObjectType,List<Id>>{
    Account.SObjectType => new List<Id>()
};
//System.debug( myMap );   
System.debug( [Select Id From Account Where Id in :myMap.get( Account.SObjectType ) limit 1] );
```

However, when you uncomment the commented line, no error is produced.

Is Salesforce using quantum computers now?? (Observing data changes it??)

If you agree with me that this is a salesforce bug, what is the appropriate procedure to report it?

Comment: It works just fine in my DE org (Summer '14), are you in a Winter '15 Sandbox or something?

Comment: Yes, I just found out that it only produces the error in sandboxes that are already on Winter '15.

Comment: Looks like a bug introduced with Winter '15 then, it should be reported. I'm afraid I don't know how you'd do that, because I'm used to doing it via the partner portal.

Comment: For now we have opened a support case, we'll see where that takes us.

Comment: Reporting bugs in Apex is notoriously difficult if you don't have Premier support - typically support will just close any case that includes the word 'Apex' and direct you to the discussion forums.

We hit this over the weekend in a sandbox that was upgraded to Winter 15 - I've raised it through MVP support. I'll update with any news that I get through that channel.

Comment: According to developer support, it is because of this known issue which is being worked on as a priority: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5buAAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First before submitting a bug, look to see if it is a known issue at [Salesforce Known Issues](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index).  You can filter the known issues by release using the tags listed on the left.

If you don't find it there you can always submit a new case.  Easiest way is by clicking the Help & Training link in the top right of your Salesforce Org. From there you can find the Contact Support link to Open a Case.